# How can we know the Avg.Pos of Keyword on hourly basis in Adword?

Tags: google-search, google-ads

How can we know the Avg.Pos of Keyword on hourly basis in Adword ?

I want to adjust my bidding based on time, So that when others are bidding high during certain time, I also want to bid higher so that, I could maintain my avg.pos to get some business.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the "target search page location" flexible bid strategy. While it doesn't allow you to specify an exact position, you can target "Top of the first search results page". Flexible bid strategies set bids at action time, so it goes far beyond hourly bid adjustments.

If you don't want to use flexibility bid strategies for some reason, you might be able to do this using Adwords Scripts. However, this could take a fair amount of setup (not to mention you have to know JavaScript pretty well) and you still might not be able to get 100% of what you want using this tool.

Lastly, you said:

> I could maintain my avg.pos to get some business.

Maintaining an average position doesn't necessarily mean getting some business. Lots of factors are at play, including your conversion rate, CTR, and impression share to name a few. I suggest tracking conversions (goals) and setting up either a CPA or ROAS bid strategy and pay what you can afford to pay per converted click. That way, you are paying directly for conversions (sales) and not buying an average position.